# How many tilted squares and rectangles exists on a square grid?

Tags: algorithm

Given a square grid, how many unique tilted squares and rectangles exist on such a grid?

For example,

2 x 2 grid has 1 tilted square.

3 x 3 grid has 4 tilted square and 4 tilted rectangles i.e. answer is 8

Tilted means they are can be formed using vertices of the grid only.

[image]
[image]

I am looking for a general formula that can be used to directly compute the number existing tilted squares and rectangles.

Comment: Iterate the grid and count?  By the way, what is a `quare` ?

Comment: What is a tilted square? Do you have a formal definition?

Comment: the question is not clear, can you provide better test cases. Also can you share what have you tried

Comment: I don't understand, why is there only 1 "tilted" square on 2x2 Grid, but 4 on the 3x3 Grid. It looks, like you can have unlimited number of unique squares... Btw. what is "unique" in this case?

Comment: Are you sure a 3x3 grid has 4 tilted rectangles? Looks like 2 to me (identical pairs). Same for squares.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog yes I am sure , you can take inner vertices too

Comment: Do the corners of these tilted shapes have to touch the outer square or are small shapes completely contained inside also allowed (e.g. a square of side ~3 in the middle of an outer area of side 100)?

Comment: @jdehesa its allowed

Comment: @KiranSaxena I see. Your graphical examples should have illustrated that. I will update my answer

Comment: @meowgoesthedog sorry Now i updated the post .Hope it helps

Comment: Don't you mean six titled squares and 2 triangles? Your second image is a square (4 little squares like 3d image, 2 squares like 2nd image and two rectangles like 1st image)

Comment: could you guys pls check my answer?

Comment: Are two squares/rectangles with the same size and rotation considered different if they are place at a different location? It looks to me that 3x3 has 6 squares and 2 rectangles if the answer is yes and 3 squares and 2 rectangles if it is no.

Answer (score 5):

Let's walk through all possible top vertex positions (`row, col`) and left vertex position (`leftcol, leftrow`).

We can see that top left segment defines orientation of rectangles. But how much valid rectangles does this segment belong to? We can shift that segment until it's ends come to integer points. So divide row ans col differences by their greatest common divisor (`6/4=>3/2`, I am not sure in English term for this operation - reduce fraction?) and choose minimum from from horizontal and vertical shift numbers. Note that segment shifted by normal to its direction, that is why in the last line y-distance is divided by x-shift and vice versa

Delphi code and results:

```
function gcd(m, n: integer): integer;
  var modulo: integer;
begin
    modulo := m mod n;
    if modulo = 0 then
        Result := n
    else
        Result := gcd(n, modulo)
end;

function DiagRectsInGrid(n: Integer): Int64;
var
  row, col, leftcol, leftrow, dr, dc, dcc, gc, dsx, dsy: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for row := 0 to n - 2 do
    for col := 1 to n - 1 do
      for leftcol := 0 to col - 1 do begin
        dc := col - leftcol;
        for leftrow := row + 1 to n - 1 do begin
          dr := leftrow - row;
          gc := gcd(dc, dr); //Greatest common divisor function
          dr := dr div gc;   //integer division
          dcc := dc div gc;
          dsx := n - col;
          dsy := n - leftrow;
          Result := Result + Min(dsx div dr, dsy div dcc);
        end;
      end;
end;

2 1
3 8
4 30
5 88
6 199
7 408
8 748
9 1280
10 2053
```

Edit:
Having this sequence, make a search for it and bingo: http://oeis.org/A113751
There is no known formula for this sequence, BTW.

Meaning of some variables:
[image]

Comment: oh wow ! but if there is no formula how we will implement it in programming?

Comment: @KiranSaxena he implemented it for you, there is code in the answer

Comment: what is `gcd` ?

Comment: gcd - Greatest common divisor function. I've added its code

Answer (score 1):

hmm, here is a square-part:
a single 2x2 can only have 1 square, so you need to check, how many times 2x2 can fit your NxN grid:

```
(n - 2 + 1)² = n² - 2n + 1
```

now, 3x3 or 4x4 can have 3-1 / 4-1 unique squares, so we set k as the single square variable:

```
(k - 1)(n - k + 1)² = ...
```

now we need to build a sum over k from 2 to N:

```
sum_{k from 2 to n} (k - 1)(n - k + 1)² = ...
```

Rectangle:
same logic: 3x3 can have 2 rectangles, so we have to count how many times 3x3 fits your NxN:

```
2*(n - 3 + 1)² = 2n² - 8n + 8
```

now replace 3 by k and build a sum:

```
sum_{k from 3 to n} 2*(n - k + 1)² = ...
```

does it make any sense???

btw. are you sure 3x3 can have 4 rectangles? I can only see 2 of them...

Comment: You are right for 3x3 - 4 small squares, 2 large squares, 2 thin rectangles